# How to call Remote EJB service using Liberty Profile

Tags: java, ejb, websphere-liberty

I need to call a remote EJB service using RMI(MDM).I am using Liberty JEE full profile. I have below code to lookup:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
Object obj = ctx.lookup("corbaname:iiop:mydomain:9810#ejb/com/dwl/base/requestHandler/beans/DWLServiceController!com.dwl.base.requestHandler.beans.DWLServiceControllerHome");

dwlServiceControllerHome = (DWLServiceControllerHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj, DWLServiceControllerHome.class);
```

**Getting below Exception:**

> [err] org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: other: corbaname evaluation error:an unknown user exception was raised: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0:  vmcid: OMG minor code: 0xa  completed: No
>   [err]   at org.apache.yoko.orb.OB.CorbanameURLScheme_impl.parse_url(CorbanameURLScheme_impl.java:232)
>   [err]   at [internal classes]
>   [err]   at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428)

Comment: I see a space here "/requestHandler/  beans/". Is that intentional?

Comment: @Tamboli there is no space.I have edited now.

Comment: Can u try escaping all the . (dots) in the url string as mentioned in the below URL: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/301721/error-while-accessing-remote-ejb-with-corbaname-ur.html